# C pipe initialization error

Tags: c, pipe

I'm busy with an assignment but I'm stuck. I get errors and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

So in the main I make three children. Between the first and second I have a pipe (`pipe12`). Between the second and the third I have a pipe (`pipe23`). Now when the first child (`reader`) is ready with reading, it closes `pipe12`, but read of the second child doesn't get an `EOF`. Secondly when the second child wants to write to `pipe23`, the child crashes.

I guess I do something wrong in the initialization of the pipes, but what?

This is the parent

```
for(childnr=2; childnr>=0;childnr--)
{
    tasks[childnr].pid=fork();
    if(tasks[childnr].pid==-1)
    {
        printf("fork error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(tasks[childnr].pid==0)
    {
        switch(childnr)
        {
            case 0:
                close(pipe12[0]);
                close(pipe23[0]);
                close(pipe23[1]);
                reader();
                break;
            case 1:
                close(pipe12[1]);
                close(pipe23[0]);
                tokenizer();
                break;
            case 2:
                close(pipe12[0]);
                close(pipe12[1]);
                close(pipe23[1]);
                evaluator();
                break;
            default:
                printf("childnr error\n");                      //errorhandling
        }           
    }
    else
        close(tasks[childnr].errorpipe[1]);
}
close(pipe12[0]);
close(pipe12[1]);
close(pipe23[0]);
close(pipe23[1]);
... continue with the parent
```

This is the first child:

```
void reader(void)
{   
    atexit(*reader_exit);
    if((readfile = fopen(calculatorfile,"r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("R send error to errorHandler");     //errpipe!
        exit(0);
    }
    char line[50];
    const char *valid_characters = "0123456789 +-/*\n";
    while(fgets ( line, sizeof line, readfile ) != NULL)
    {
        printf("R reading ...%s",line);
        char *c = line;
        while(*c)
        {
            if(!strchr(valid_characters,*c))
            {
                printf("R invalid character: %c in %s",*c,line);
                line[0]=0;
                break;
            }
            c++;
        }
        write(pipe12[1],line,sizeof line);
    }
    exit(0);
}

void reader_exit(void)
{
    printf("R reader exit\n");
    fclose(readfile);
    close(pipe12[1]);
    close(tasks[childnr].errorpipe[1]);
}
```

And the second child:

```
void tokenizer(void)
{
    atexit(*tokenizer_exit);
    char buffer[50];
    while(read(pipe12[0],buffer,sizeof buffer)!=EOF)
    {
        printf("T %s",buffer);
        char *token = strtok(buffer," ");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            printf("T %s\n",token);
            write(pipe23[1],token,sizeof token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        sleep(2);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You could improve the generality of your reader by passing the file descriptor to it: `reader(pipe12[1])`.  Similarly with the tokenizer: `tokenizer(pipe12[0], pipe23[1]);`, and the evaluator: `evaluator(pipe23[0]);`.  For the reader, you should probably pass the file name too: `reader(calculatorfile, pipe12[1]);`.

Comment: How does the child process crash?  `SIGPIPE` or  `SIGSEGV`/`SIGBUS`?

Comment: I dont know, how can I find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that `read()` returns 0 on EOF, not -1 or EOF.

Your code should have loops like:

```
while (read(pipe12[0], buffer, sizeof buffer) > 0)
```

---

I suggest avoiding the functions registered with `atexit()`; they force you to use global variables.  Have your primary child functions do their own cleanup.  This will make it easier to implement the suggestion made in a comment:

> You could improve the generality of your reader by passing the file descriptor to it, and similarly with the tokenizer and the evaluator:
>
> ```
> reader(pipe12[1])
> tokenizer(pipe12[0], pipe23[1]);
> evaluator(pipe23[0]);
> ```
>
> For the reader, you should probably pass the file name too:
>
> ```
> reader(calculatorfile, pipe12[1]);
> ```

---

This code just about works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atexit() */
#include <string.h>

static int pipe12[2];
static int pipe23[2];

struct task
{
    pid_t pid;
};
static struct task tasks[5];

static void evaluator(int i_fd);
static void tokenizer(int i_fd, int o_fd);
static void reader(char const *file, int o_fd);

int main(void)
{
    pipe(pipe12);
    pipe(pipe23);
    for (int childnr=2; childnr>=0;childnr--)
    {
        tasks[childnr].pid=fork();
        if (tasks[childnr].pid==-1)
        {
            printf("fork error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (tasks[childnr].pid==0)
        {
            switch (childnr)
            {
                case 0:
                    close(pipe12[0]);
                    close(pipe23[0]);
                    close(pipe23[1]);
                    reader("data-file", pipe12[1]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    close(pipe12[1]);
                    close(pipe23[0]);
                    tokenizer(pipe12[0], pipe23[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    close(pipe12[0]);
                    close(pipe12[1]);
                    close(pipe23[1]);
                    evaluator(pipe23[0]);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("childnr error\n");                      //errorhandling
                    break;
            }           
        }
    }
    close(pipe12[0]);
    close(pipe12[1]);
    close(pipe23[0]);
    close(pipe23[1]);

    printf("Parent waiting...\n");
    while (wait(0) != -1)
        ;
    printf("Brats are all dead!\n");
    return(0);
}

static void reader(char const *file, int o_fd)
{   
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen(file, "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("R send error to errorHandler");     //errpipe!
        exit(0);
    }
    char line[50];
    const char *valid_characters = "0123456789 +-/*\n";
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("RI %s", line);
        char *c = line;
        while (*c)
        {
            if (!strchr(valid_characters, *c))
            {
                printf("R invalid character: %c in %s\n", *c, line);
                line[0] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            c++;
        }
        if (line[0] != '\0')
        {
            printf("RO %s", line);
            write(o_fd, line, strlen(line));
        }
    }
    close(o_fd);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Reader exiting\n");
    exit(0);
}

static void tokenizer(int i_fd, int o_fd)
{
    char buffer[50];
    int nbytes;
    while ((nbytes = read(i_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
    {
        buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
        printf("TI %*s\n", nbytes, buffer);
        char *token = strtok(buffer, " \n");
        while (token!=NULL)
        {
            printf("TO %s\n", token);
            write(o_fd, token, strlen(token));
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        sleep(2);
    }
    printf("Tokenizer exiting\n");
    exit(0);
}

static void evaluator(int i_fd)
{
    char buffer[50];
    int nbytes;
    while ((nbytes = read(i_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
    {
        printf("EI %*s\n", nbytes, buffer);
        buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
        char *token = strtok(buffer, " ");
        while (token!=NULL)
        {
            printf("EO %s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        sleep(2);
    }
    close(i_fd);
    printf("Evaluator exiting\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Given a data file containing:

```
123 456
123 + 234 * 547 / 987 - 1
```

One run of the program produced:

```
Parent waiting...
RI 123 456
RO 123 456
RI 123 + 234 * 547 / 987 - 1
RO 123 + 234 * 547 / 987 - 1
Reader exiting
TI 123 456

TO 123
TO 456

EI 123
EO 123
TI 123 + 234 * 547 / 987 - 1
EI 456

TO 123
TO +
TO 234
TO *

TO 547
TO /
EO 456

TO 987
TO -
TO 1

EI 123+234*547/987-1

EO 123+234*547/987-1

Tokenizer exiting
Evaluator exiting
Brats are all dead!
```

Note that data read with `read()` has to be explicitly null terminated; data read with `fgets()` does not.  Note also how the basic debugging was put in place; all inputs are echoed, all outputs to the next program are echoed too.  This makes it easy (or, at least, easier) to see where there might be problems.  In extreme cases, it would be better to write to `stderr`, or to `fflush()` after every `printf()`.  There are many details that are sub-optimal, such as using `printf()` with just a single string argument.  The tasks structure is redundant in this code.  The pipe arrays could be local variables in the revised code.

Comment: This has solved the problem with the read that didn't end. But the program still crashes at the first writ in the tokenizer.

Comment: The example run shows the tokenizer not crashing and writing successfully to the evaluator.  What's different about your code and my code?

Comment: Ok I works now. I think the problem was that I had not written any code yet for the evaluator so that one did not yet read what the tokenizer puts on the pipe. Thanks